# Attach latest build generated file (not log file) from Jenkins emailext?

Tags: jenkins, email-attachments

I am running a Jenkins pipline which is calling a script
In following example, running a script which is generating output file with issue_{datetime}.txt
I want to send this file as attachment. However, as file name is generated every time with separate date time stamps not able to find a way to attach file.
e.g.

```
 pipeline {
   agent any
   stages{
      stage('Start Build'){
          steps{
             python run.py
           }
      }
   }
  post {
    always {
            echo ("${email_id}")
            emailext from: 'xyz@yahoo.com', attachmentsPattern: 'resources/*.xlsx', 
            to: "${email_id}",     
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OUTPUT_FILE = sh(script: 'ls -t resources/issue*.xlsx | head -1', returnStdout: true)
emailext from: 'test@yahoo.com', attachmentsPattern:"${OUTPUT_FILE}"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this try this,

```
emailext attachmentsPattern: '**/resources/*.xlsx', body: 'Find attachments', subject: 'Attachment', to: 'test@ab.org'
```

Comment: I tried this but it's attaching all xlsx file from that location.

Comment: @jigar then add only the files which you are interested

Comment: I  have to pull the latest generated file which contains timestamp. I was able to find solution by picking up latest file in script output and used it as attachment.